# update one specific row from an existing user by a webform

Tags: webforms

i have try multiple ways but i need to update an specific row from an existing user by a webform i have try this code but i have some thing wrong on the code.

```html
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: index.php");
}

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo '<form action="" method="post">';
    echo '<div style="float:left">';
    echo '<table border="1" bordercolor="#000000">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>link</td>';
    echo '<td><input type="text" name="user_wallet" value="'.$row['user_wallet'].'"></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table></div>';
    echo '</form><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />';
}
}
if(isset($_POST['update'])){

   $user_wallet = $_POST['user_wallet'];
   

    $sql = mysqli_query("UPDATE users SET user_wallet = '$user_wallet' WHERE id = '$id'");

    $retval = mysqli_query( $sql, $con );

    if(! $retval ){
        die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    echo "Updated data successfully\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: The bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt page is not working bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt can not process this request for time. 500